# Python requests not working on some websites

Tags: python

I have these lines of code and when you insert a website such as "github.com/", the checker works accurately but when I try websites such as "tiktok.com/@" or "instagram.com/", it doesn't work properly.
Any explanation? I'm wondering why it works on some websites while it doesn't on other.

```
import random, string, requests, time
from colorama import Fore
import os

hmletters = int(input('How many letters do you want to check : '))
print("")
websit = input('What is the website : ')
print("")
web = list(websit)
webs = web[:-1]
webss = ''.join(webs)
print()
time.sleep(.3)
while True:
    usernames = ('').join(random.choices(string.ascii_lowercase + string.digits, k=hmletters))
    r = requests.get(f'https://{websit}{usernames}')
    if r.status_code == 200:
        print("Unavailable")
    else:
        print("Available")
        f = open("availables.txt", "a", encoding='utf-8')
        f.write(f"{usernames} | Might be Available or Banned on => {webss} | \n")
```

EDIT:

Without the input: For github, it works perfectly and it separates taken and available usernames but for instagram, all names are available.

```
import random, string, requests, time
from colorama import Fore
import os

hmletters = 4
print("")
websit = "instagram.com/"
print("")
web = list(websit)
webs = web[:-1]
webss = ''.join(webs)
print()
time.sleep(.3)


#taken (instagram)
usernames = ('').join("chris")
r = requests.get(f'https://{websit}{usernames}')
if r.status_code == 200:
    print("Unavailable")
else:
    print("Available")
    f = open("availables.txt", "a", encoding='utf-8')
    f.write(f"{usernames} | Might be Available or Banned on => {webss} | \n")


#available (instagram)
usernames = ('').join("twh1d2")
r = requests.get(f'https://{websit}{usernames}')
if r.status_code == 200:
    print("Unavailable")
else:
    print("Available"")
    f = open("availables.txt", "a", encoding='utf-8')
    f.write(f"{usernames} | Might be Available or Banned on => {webss} | \n")






    #For GITHUB


#taken (github)
usernames = ('').join("chris")
r = requests.get(f'https://github.com/{usernames}')
if r.status_code == 200:
    print(Fore.CYAN+"[-] "+Fore.RED + "Unavailable"+ Fore.WHITE +' |=>'+Fore.YELLOW+ f' {usernames}'+Fore.WHITE+" <=|"+Fore.CYAN+" [-]")
else:
    print(Fore.CYAN+"[-] "+Fore.GREEN + "Available" + Fore.WHITE + ' |=>' + Fore.LIGHTMAGENTA_EX + f' {usernames}'+Fore.WHITE+" <=|" + Fore.CYAN + " [+]")
    f = open("availables.txt", "a", encoding='utf-8')
    f.write(f"{usernames} | Might be Available or Banned on => {webss} | \n")


#available (github)
usernames = ('').join("twh1d2")
r = requests.get(f'https://github.com/{usernames}')
if r.status_code == 200:
    print(Fore.CYAN+"[-] "+Fore.RED + "Unavailable"+ Fore.WHITE +' |=>'+Fore.YELLOW+ f' {usernames}'+Fore.WHITE+" <=|"+Fore.CYAN+" [-]")
else:
    print(Fore.CYAN+"[-] "+Fore.GREEN + "Available" + Fore.WHITE + ' |=>' + Fore.LIGHTMAGENTA_EX + f' {usernames}'+Fore.WHITE+" <=|" + Fore.CYAN + " [+]")
    f = open("availables.txt", "a", encoding='utf-8')
    f.write(f"{usernames} | Might be Available or Banned on => {webss} | \n")
```

Comment: Sorry but this question is very vague. What does not work? What did you expect and what actually happens?

Comment: Please edit an an example URL into your code, not using the `input()` but hardcoded, and show the _full_ error message you get, as text, from that specific URL.

Comment: There are other valid status code than `200`.

Comment: Sorry for being unspecific, it doesn't work meaning that when I provide unavailable usernames such as "chris", on "instagram.com/", it returns as available.

Comment: Some websites won't give you permission for `requests`

Comment: I edited the post to show the hardcoded one. I am not getting an error message but more of a misfunction.

Comment: What can I do for websites that won't give permission for requests? Is it impossible to check or are there other ways to check?